# zend form element inside a table

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm looking for a way that I can add my zend form element inside a table, I tried this method below but its not working:I want this element to be inside the table below it.example pic below

```
 $name2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('search');
 $name2->setLabel('Search Enterprise Name:');       
 $name2->addValidator('NotEmpty')       
            ->setDecorators(array( 
                        'FormElements',
                        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table', 'id' => 't1')), 'Form', 
                        ));

<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 0;">
<table class='spreadsheet dataTable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='' id="t1">
<thead> 

<tr role="row">
<th>ENTER SERVICE PROVIDER USED</th>

</tr>
</thead>    
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('I work!')">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Should I echo the element back in my phtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can add the item into view.
Declare your item in a form `Application_Form_Toto`.

In your action to declare your form in the view

```
$form = new Application_Form_Toto();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

Call your element in your HTML (your view)

```
<table>...<tr>...<td><?php echo $this->form->search;?></td>...</tr>...</table>
```

Comment: But I need to ask how do I make sure the same element does not appear in my zend form above but instead only in my table below the form.

Comment: If your item belongs to a form and call the form AND the element into the view, the two will appear

Comment: Hey doydoy I just created a second form for the elements and changed the variable name for the second form to form2 and it worked fine. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve the single element from the form file then,

```
class Form_Test() {
public function init() {
    $name2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('search');
    $name2->setLabel('Search Enterprise Name:');       
    $name2->addValidator('NotEmpty')       
        ->setDecorators(array( 
                    'FormElements',
                    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table', 'id' => 't1')), 'Form', 
                    ));
    }
}
```

In the controller file:

```
$form = new Form_test();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

In the view file you can call the single element only as,

```
<table>...<tr>...<td><?php echo $this->form->getElement("search");?></td>...</tr>...</table>
```

Also, if you do not want your design to be controlled from decorators, you can simply call removeDecorator() in form and adjust your design from view itself with this method.